# How can i make user enter "string" and enter (index) and remove this (index) from "string" which he entered?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Text = input(">> Please, Enter The Text: ")
index_X = input(">> Please, Enter The index_X which you want to remove from 'Text': ")
print(Text.remove(index_X))
```

i tried to use replace method
but i think there is another way

Comment: Welcome to SO! `input()` in python always take `string` as an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the piece of the string prior to the index and then the piece of the string after the index and put them together.

```py
Text = input(">> Please, Enter The Text: ")
index_X = int(input(">> Please, Enter The index_X which you want to remove from 'Text': ")) #convert to int
new_text = Text[:index_X] + Text[index_X+1:]
print(new_text)
```

Comment: what if user input "pythonx" as a string and input -1 as a index to remove character "x" from "pythonx"

Comment: if you try it, you'll see that it will return 'pythonpythonx'. If you don't want your user to be able to do this, then check if index_x > 0 and make them try again if it isn't.

Comment: or, if you want them to be able to do this, then yea you'll need to adjust the code to handle it.